# CSS/Bootstrap Grid Row Alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dreamweaver

I can't understand why this nested grid row has the space above it. I want to align it to the center. I'd like to just select and align to center much like Excel.

I have a fluid container with a nested grid row with three columns and another grid row nested in the first column, but its like I've pressed return and there's a space above it.

TIA!

[gridrow alignment issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODkuS.png)

```css
.row>div:not(.row) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.row .row>div {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6">Col content</div>
        <div class="col-xl-6">Col content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">Col content</div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">Col content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. We don't debug images.

Comment: You're going to want to review the [Bootstrap grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) and understand how the mobile-first strategy impacts your layout. Columns wrap on small screens, and since you've only applied column classes for _extra large_ screens you don't have control of that behavior.

Comment: thanks @isherwood and apologies for my poor question.. ill get the hang of it! ill try and take in the edit

Comment: Look at the demo above in full page mode and see how it differs from the compact view.

Comment: I posted the wrong grid docs. Here's the [Bootstrap 4 version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

but use this

```
   <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
     //like your code
   </div>
```

col-12 is only an example, change with the number that you want.

Comment: I don't understand your first statement. Rows should always be in containers, as they balance each others' margins.